# Pylons routing, what is the location attribute?

Tags: python, pylons

I'm looking at the reddit source code and ran into a route that looks like the following:

`mc('/prefs/:location', controller='forms', action='prefs', location='options')`

Searching the documentation here, I can't find anything related to the `location` attribute:

https://thejimmyg.github.io/pylonsbook/en/1.0/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html

What is `location='options'` supposed to do for this route?

Comment: So little information to go on.  The only thing anyone can do is confirm that Mapper and its methods don't take a location variable.  What is mc()?  It's possible it's a wrapper for the Mapper object that adds some logic for a location attribute, but there really isn't enough information to go on.  Reddit is a big place with a lot of source code.  Maybe post more of the one you're looking at?  Like the definition of mc().

Comment: mc seems to just be an instance of `Mapper`. `map = Mapper(explicit=False)    
        map.minimization = True
       mc = map.connect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routes.Mapper.connect() takes *args and **kwargs as arguments.  Since `locations='options'` is a valid **kwargs entry and in a valid location, it will be accepted as a valid passed variable.  I don't have the source code available, so I don't know what connect() will do with this variable.  I'm guessing it simply attaches the extra name=value pairs to the created URLs.

You can find more documentation here: http://routes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mapper.html#routes.mapper.Mapper.connect